# catkin command passes with non-existent ROS package "pcl"

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [pcl tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials#Create_a_ROS_package),

```
catkin_create_pkg my_pcl_tutorial pcl pcl_ros roscpp sensor_msgs
```

AFAIK there's no package called `pcl` in `hydro`, and `catkin_create_pkg` only takes `catkin packages` as an argument, but this command passes without errors and creates a package. Why is it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114231/catkin-command-passes-with-non-existent-ros-package-%22pcl%22/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2014-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

When you call catkin_create_pkg it just lists everything after the package name as a dependency in the package.xml file, so you could probably put anything in there and it would at least successfully run that command. It may not actually compile once you get to the `catkin_make` step.

Also as a side note: PCL is the Point Cloud Library, and the ros package for it is called ros-hydro-pcl-ros in your package manager (assuming you're using Ubuntu).

-Tim

---

Originally posted by [Tim Sweet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5998/tim-sweet/) with karma: 267 on 2014-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-02**:
Added to that, the upstream PCL package is called pcl, which is a valid rosdep dependency.